# Question about completion of measure. $M\subset N\Rightarrow\bar{M}\subset\bar{N}$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,M,\mu), (Y,N,\lambda)$ is measure space, and $(X,\bar{M},\bar{\mu}), (Y,\bar{N},\bar{\lambda})$ is its completion.

If $M\subset N,$ does $\bar{M}\subset\bar{N}$ hold ?

I felt that it was not valid, but I could not come up with a counterexample.
If the claim is valid, please prove it.

Comment: Take $\lambda (E)=\infty$ for every non-empty Borel set $E$and $\mu$ to be Lebesgue measure on the Borel  sigma algebre of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, I don't understand it, so can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: If $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set which is not a Borel set then it belongs to $\overline M$ but no to $\overline N$.